# How do I achieve perfect shrinkwrap for the following mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, shrinkwrap, solidify-modifier

[image]

Trying to achieve perfect solidity to the shrinkwrap parts of my object. I can see the weird shading/stretching of mesh issue, how do I resolve it, what are the exact steps needed for me to do it?

This is the model I am trying to build btw:
[image]

[image]